# Changing the color of a ToggleSwitch for UWP using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I would like to change the color of the toggle switch for UWP on a `Xamarin.Forms` project. I think there is 2 ways to go about it which is either a custom renderer or an effect. So I tried making an effect, but it seems like somehow I am still unable to change the toggle switch borders. Would anyone be kind enough to help me out?

Below is my code:
In UWP, the FocusEffect.cs file,

```
namespace EffectsDemo.UWP
{
    public class FocusEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            try
            {
               (Control as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);                   
                (Control as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control).BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                (Control as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                 (Element as Switch).IsInNativeLayout = false;
                (Control as ToggleSwitch).BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.WhiteSmoke);
                (Control as ToggleSwitch).BorderThickness = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(500);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Cannot set property on attached control. Error: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the default `ToggleSwitch` style in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299159.aspx) or in the `generic.xaml` file, you will find out that its border is defined like the following:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="OuterBorder"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Height="20"
            Width="44"
            RadiusX="10"
            RadiusY="10"
            Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
            StrokeThickness="2" />
```

As you can see, the `Stroke` brush is **hardcoded into the default template** and does not depend on the `BorderBrush` value you set to the control. This means the only way to achieve this will be to write a **custom style inside the UWP project** for the control, where you will use the brush you actually want and then set it within a **custom renderer**.